# Slick compile query with Set[Int] parameter

Tags: postgresql, scala, prepared-statement, slick, slick-3.0

I have a query that takes `Seq[Int]` as it's argument (and performs filtering like `WHERE x IN (...)`), and I need to compile it since this query is failry complex. However, when I try the naive approach:

```
Compiled((xs: Set[Int]) => someQuery.filter(_.x inSet xs))
```

It fails with message that

```
Computation of type Set[Int] => Query[SomeTable, SomeValue, Seq] cannot be compiled (as type C)
```

Can Slick compile queries that takes a sets of integer as parameters?

**UPDATE:** I use PostgreSQL as database, so it can be possible to use arrays instead of `IN` clause, but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the PostgreSQL database, the solution is much simpler than I expected.

First of all, there is a need of special Slick driver for PostgreSQL that support arrays. It usually already included in projects that rely on PgSQL features, so there is no trouble at all. I use [this driver](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg).

The main idea is to replace plain SQL `IN (...)` clause which takes the same amount of bind parameters as the amount of items in list, and thus cannot be statically compiled by Slick with PgSQL-specific array operator `x = ANY(arr)`, which takes only one parameter for the array. It's easy to do with code like this:

```
val compiledQuery = Compiled((x: Rep[List[Int]]) => query.filter(_.id === x.any))
```

This code will generate query like `WHERE x = ANY(?)` which will use only one parameter, so Slick will accept it for compilation.